# How to get the second to last element from a multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a `boost::multi_index_container` indexed by `hashed_unique` and `sequenced`. How can I get the second from the last element from this container?

```
struct MyContainer : public mi::multi_index_container<
    MyStruct,
    mi::indexed_by<
        mi::hashed_unique<
          mi::tag<hashed>,
          %some stuff%,
          %some stuff%,
          %some stuff%>
        >,
        mi::sequenced<mi::tag<sequenced> >
    >
>
{ };
```

As the container is hashed, I can find any element by its hash. But in my case, I do not know the hash of the second-to-last element. However, I know the hash of the last element and hence can get the last element.

```
MyContainer::iterator myIter = m_table.find(hashOfLast);
```

Can I use this `myIter` to get an iterator to the previous element?

Edit:

Can I do something like this?

```
MyContainer::nth_index<1>::type& seqIdx = m_table.get<1>();
auto current = seqIdx.rbegin();
auto last = seqIdx.rend();

if(current != last){
    current++;
    //How to get the hash of this element now?
}
```

Comment: Do you mean second to last a) according to the order elements appear in the hashed index or b) according to the order in the sequenced index?

Comment: According to the sequences index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [iterator projection](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#projection) as follows:

```
MyContainer::index<sequenced>::type::iterator it=
  m_table.get<sequenced>().end(); // iterator to end of sequenced index
--it;--it; // two steps back
MyContainer::iterator myIter=m_table.project<hashed>(it); // project into the hashed index
```

Note that the same technique can be used for the one-to-last position, which might dispense you with the need to keep your `hashOfLast` variable.

> Can I use this `myIter` to get an iterator to the previous element?

No (unless you resort to iterator projection as shown above), because of two reasons:

- Hashed index iterators (unlike those of sequenced indices) are not bidirectional (incrementable and decrementable), just forward (incrementable).
- Even if `myIter`coud be decremented, it wouldn't point to the element at the second-to-last position in the sequenced index: traversal orders in both indices are completely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar to what I just showed in my edit. Will this work?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the edited part of your post: is it the *hash value* of `*current` you want to obtain? This has little to do with the question you originally posed.

Comment: I want to obtain the second from last element as you answered earlier. But I thought of another way to accomplish the task and showed that in edit. `*current*` according to me is the second to last element. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have another question. How to obtain the hash of the second to last element, we just found? As this is related to my original question, I did not want to post another question.

Comment: Also, in your solution can you explain we need to project `it` onto hashed index? Isn't `it` the iterator to the second element?

Comment: 1. Yep, `current` does point to the second to last element, but you have to make sure your container has at least two elements, otherwise `*current` would fail. I don't see any advantage in using reverse iterators rather than just calling `--`  twice on `end()` (with appropriate checking that the size of the container is >=2).

Comment: 2. To obtain the hash value of an element pointed to by `it` you can do `m_table.hash_function()(m_table.key_extractor()(*it))`.

Comment: 3. Yes, `it` points to the second-to-last element, the same as `myIter`, both both iterators are of different types --the first belongs to the sequenced index, the second to the hashed one. Whether `it` suffices or you need `myIter` depends on what you plan to do with the iterator afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanations